# Need help writing a ExactTarget Query to pull email addresses from multiple Data Extensions and put in another Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to write a query that would find any Data Extension that has been added to the system within the past day and the data extension name begins with "ABC" for example. I then want to pull all email addresses from the "Email" column within those data extensions and add them to a different data extension. I was thinking it would be something like:

```
Select  Email (somehow find all DE's that start with ABC) 
From DE's
Where (Date is less then or equal to 24 hours ago)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in means in SFMC to determine if "any *Data Extension* ... has been added to the system in the past day".

You could set up a Script Activity* in Automation Studio and use the [SSJS API](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/) to retrieve all of the Data Extensions and [create a Query Definition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/query_definition_server_side_javascript_functions/) that includes the *new* Data Extensions from first API call with API and execute it.

*SFMC Support will have to enable Script Activities for you.  They are not enabled by default.